# How to Add Date & Time in php from different field in Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, date, time

I have a postgresql query that I want to input in php.

```
select t1.userid, t1.date_in, t1.check_in, t2.checktime, t3.alias from t1
inner join t2 on t2.checktime= date_in + check_in and t1.userid=t2.userid
inner join t3 on t2.sn=t3.sn;
```

I already tried using this

```
$this->db->select('t1.userid, t1.date_in, t1.check_in, t2.checktime, t3.alias');
$this->db->from ('t1');
$this->db->join ('t2', 't2.checktime = (date_in + check_in) and  (t1.userid=t2.userid)');
$this->db->join ('t3', 't2.sn=t3.sn');
$data = $this->db->get();
if($data)
return $data['alias'];
else
return false;
```

I always get false. I already tried numerous times to change but still dont get the same result just like query in database.
FYI. date_in = date format, check_in = time format.

Can some one help me regarding this? Thanks before.

Comment: use `print_r($this->db->last_query());` to find out what query is built in codeigniter.

Comment: Do you actually mean that `date_in = date format, check_in = time format` are fields that are of date and time types in the table?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, thats right.

Comment: @JitendraYadav I already used it. and it seems fine for me. but I dont know where is wrong with this.

Comment: Include the output of the `print` in your question, because obviously the query is not correct or you would not be here.

Comment: SELECT "process"."userid", "process"."date_in", "process"."check_in", "checkinout"."checktime", "iclock"."alias" FROM "process" JOIN "checkinout" ON "checkinout"."checktime" = ("date_in" + check_in) and (process.userid=checkinout.userid) JOIN "iclock" ON "checkinout"."sn"="iclock"."sn" WHERE "userid" = '293'